# Embed dash plots on internal google site

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, plotly-dash, google-sites

I have built a report in Dash, which I am hosting on aws elastic beanstalk.

Now, I'd like to to emded this report into our company's internal google sites page.

I tried to use `<iframe>`, but that does not work. Although just pasting the link to a browser works.

`<iframe src="http://path.elasticbeanstalk.com/" width=700 height=600>`

Furthermore, I have to make sure that nobody else can access the report if the link gets outside. For that, I was playing with cognito, but I don't know if I should give access to specific google accounts or just the google site somehow?